# Text trimming in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, texttrimming

can somebody explain me how do I use the code in here http://nerdplusart.com/texttrimming-textblock-for-silverlight to trim texts?

I've been searching for a solution to trim my texts to a determined lenght and add an ellipsis to the end, but I only find links to that code that I don't know how to use!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use it as you would and instead of a `TextBlock`.
So (assuming you save that source as is into your app):

```
<PixelLab:DynamicTextBlock Text="some really really really really really long text that won't fit on a line" />
```

And be sure to set the appropriate namepace:

```
xmlns:PixelLab="clr-namespace:PixelLab"
```

Comment: so easy! but as a newbie I don't have the concepts very clear yet! Thank you!